# Is there a way to retrieve a set or array of keys for a given NSManagedObject?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

For any given NSManagedObject, is there any method to return a set or array of keys (attribute names) for that particular NSManagedObject? I've tried looking around in NSObject & NSManagedObject docs but found nothing. Something that functions like NSDictionary 'allKeys' would be what I need, ie.

```
myArrayOfKeys = [myDict allKeys]
```

I presume there must be an easier way of handling large numbers of attributes eg. iterating over an array of keys.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`-[NSManagedObject entity]` returns the [`NSEntityDescription`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSEntityDescription_Class/NSEntityDescription.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSEntityDescription). This then lets you find its properties, in particular if you just want the attribute names you can get `-[NSEntityDescription attributesByName]`, a dictionary where each key is an attribute name and each value is a [`NSAttributeDescription`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSAttributeDescription_Class/reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSAttributeDescription).

Comment: myNSManagedObject.entity.attributesByName.keys

Answer (score 5):

I wrote the following based on James' advice, and presume it might be useful to others troubleshooting their code and using his answer; thanks James!

// from Apple's Master Detail template project
- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{

```
//! Apple standard template code
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

//! Slowburner addition to view the managedObject's keys
NSEntityDescription *attDesc = [newManagedObject entity];
NSDictionary *attributesByName = [attDesc attributesByName];
NSLog(@"Names:%@",[attributesByName allKeys]);

//! shortcut to avoid whatever problem you're troubleshooting
return;
```